# making input fields blank when clicking a button using knockout only

Tags: html, knockout.js

I want to use only knockout to implement the following: 
- I want to make my input fields blank when "button1" is clicked and display the values back when "button2" is clicked. The input fields are data binded by their respective observables. So, I am not sure how I should make the observables null and then display them back when button2 is clicked.

Code:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.comment = ko.observable("hi there"); 
    self.message = ko.observable("hello"); 
}

vm = new ViewModel(); 
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**My approach:**

Here are the two methods I tried implementing but did not work at all:

```
myShow: function() { 
   comment = ko.observable(""); 
},

myHide: function() {
    message = ko.observable(""); 
},
```

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to temporarily save the values, right? Use a private variable in the viewmodel, like this.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.comment = ko.observable("");
    self.message = ko.observable("");

    var comment, message;
    self.store = function() {
        comment = self.comment();
        message = self.message();
        self.comment("");
        self.message("");
    };
    self.show = function() {
        self.comment(comment);
        self.message(message);
    };    
};
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/KGSUD/)